# setting up visual studio code for c++, but unable to compile

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have installed visual studio 2019 which works fine for  c++ but unable to create folders and sections to store multiple code files. So thought of switching to visual studio code and followed all tutorials available on youtube and documentation. But Visual studio IDE has got nothing showing up when Run Build task is initiated, which is expected to show the c++ extension downloaded. Mingw64 is installed and checked in the terminal too.

no output or terminal opened on Run

[image]

compiler installation checked

[image]

Comment: It does say build finished succesfully. Have you tried running helloworld.exe from terminal?

Comment: How should I run this from terminal? I am using windows.

Comment: If youre in the same directory all you have to do is type the filename. `helloworld.exe` in the cmd, if its powershell, then `./helloworld.exe`. Also note that for exe files you dont need to explicitly mention `.exe` at the end of the file name

Comment: Powershell method should work on cmd too. And also if youre not in the same path as that of the file, either change directory by typing `cd path/to/file` or run directly by typing `path/to/file/helloworld.exe`. where `path/to/file` is the directory of your `helloworld.exe` file

Comment: thanks. it is working from both command prompt and powershell now.

Comment: Youre welcome, i'll turn this into an answer so you can accept it and this question isnt left unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

From the image attached regarding no output in the terminal or terminal opened, it looks like the exe is made because it says 'Build finsihed succesfully'. You'll need to run this executable from the terminal.

For this, if youre in the same directory all you have to do is type the filename. `helloworld.exe` in the cmd, if its powershell, then `./helloworld.exe`. (Also note that for exe files you dont need to explicitly mention .exe at the end of the file name)

The powershell method should work on cmd too.

And if youre not in the same directory as the executable, you can either change directory by typing `cd path/to/file` and proceed as above, or run directly by typing `path/to/file/helloworld.exe`. where `path/to/file` is the directory of your `helloworld.exe` file